# CSS background error in my page

Tags: css, joomla

I made a webpage, but I have a problem with my menu CSS.

http://www.kezszobor.hu

My problem is that when the mouse hovers over the menu, the hover background does not fit the full button.

This is a Joomla + Cinch Menu module.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Provide the code you are using so we can help

Comment: that is the module css:
'code'
ul.flyout-menu .menu-link a:hover {
 min-height:15px;
 font-size:12px;
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 padding:7px 0px 0px 7px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 font-family:arial;
 background:url(../images/menu_2.png) repeat;
 background-size: 202px 89px; 
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
ul.flyout-menu .menu-link a:link {
  min-height: 30px;
}

ul.flyout-menu.text-left .menu-link {
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

ul.flyout-menu .item-wrapper {
  height: 30px;
}

ul.flyout-menu li {
  height: 30px;
}
```

If you put it at the bottom of template.css file, it will overwrite the current values and you should be set to go.

Comment: sorry, it worked :) not in template.css, in module css ('flyout.css'), when i wrote to this css, it's worked ;) thank you!!!!!!

Comment: No worries, I thought it would go in template.css, I am not familiar with Joomla. But glad it worked :)